# Add "filler" column to Query in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to query a range A1:B3 with two columns, adding an initial third column with a character.

This is the data:

[image]

These are my query attempts:

=QUERY($A$1:$B$3,"SELECT '-', A, B")

=QUERY($A$1:$B$3,"SELECT '-', A, B",0)

This is the output

[image]

Would love a solution that looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for considering my query.

Kent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add a second query where you use an offset ?

```
=QUERY(QUERY($A$1:$B$3,"SELECT '-', A, B",0), "offset 1")
```

[image]

Comment: That certainly works, but the data I've provided is much simpler than in the actual sheets and my query more complex. So, I'm really looking for a way to solve this within the =QUERY() solution rather than with ArrayFormula(). If I can't do that , I may need to apply ArrayFormula to my query result. Any ideas on how to do this with a Query?

Comment: All this does, is adds one more column to the datarange. So it shoulde be possible to wrap  the query around it ? See example.

Comment: Yes, that also works. But my solution requires appending multiple queries with lots of variable rows. The Array solution within the query is not workable. It might be possible to apply it post-Query, but I'm still convinced (wrongly?) that there must be a way to add a filler line to a query without the problem I'm facing. I do it in SQL all of the time. It's super easy. Note ... it ALMOST works as is. I have no idea why the query is adding the line "-"().

Comment: Yes, as I said, that does work. But it's not a workable solution for my data. BTW, just tried a filter(). Creates a circular dependency given my data structure.

Comment: Still hoping for a direct query solution, but did resolve the problem by creating a query on my query. A bit of a workaround, but shouldn't be necessary. =QUERY() should have a way of directly added blanks and fillers to the output.

Comment: Thanks for the help, JPV!

Comment: This was more fully resolved in another thread. The problem is created because, when custom columns are added to the query, the 0 parameter at the end eliminates only the headers of the columns in the original dataset and NOT for the custom column. By default, the QUERY yields a column name for the custom column that thus must be suppressed. This is done by adding a label format command, like this, to the query: =QUERY($A$1:$B$3, "SELECT '-', A, B LABEL '-' ''", 0). In essence, this replaces the default column '-' with the content ''. Problem, solved.